# Como utilizar a função Chr() no C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++-builder

Preciso de um exemplo do uso da função `Chr()` ou algo equivalente no C++ Builder.

Estou precisando para fazer uma função para descriptografar a senha do banco de dados.

Comment: Porque você quer usar esta função? Ela faz parte do Delphi, não seria melhor usar coisas próprias do C++? Mostre que você está fazendo pra ver se tem solução melhor.

Comment: Na verdade formulei mal a pergunta. Poderia ser algo equivalente a essa função, só que no C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O C++ é diferente do Delphi nesse aspecto. O tipo `char` em C++ é ao mesmo tempo um tipo numérico e de texto. Você pode tanto armazenar em uma variável `char` a representação textual do caractere (com aspas simples) como usar um número simples (em geral equivalente a um único byte). Então a conversão não se faz necessária. Guarde o número que iria passar para a função `Chr()` e já obterá o caractere desejado. Assim:

```
char x = 65; //é o caractere A
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/33Dc99). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xizieged-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/CharToInt.cpp).

Obviamente que onde há um número literal pode ser uma variável ou expressão que resulte neste número.

Se desejar usar um caractere multi-byte, o tipo mais adequado é o [`wchar_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/wchar_t).

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Segue o resultado da função para descriptografar.

```
String DesprotegeSenhaSQL(String senha)
{
int i, j;
String aux, texto;

j=1;
for(i=1; i<=senha.Length();i++)
{
    if (senha.SubString(i,1)!="-" && senha.SubString(i,1)!="#")
    {
      aux = aux+senha.SubString(i,1);
    }
    else
    {
       try {
         texto=texto+char(StrToInt(aux)-j);
       } catch(Exception &ex)
       {
        exit;
       }
       j=j+1;
       aux="";
    }
 }
return texto;
}
```